# Understanding includes

Tags: php

i just started coding php and i have a problem about including files

i've created 3 files

> main.php

```
<?php
include "dbprovider.php";
$param = $_GET["q"];
if(!isset($param) || $param == ""){echo "Parameter null"; return;}

switch ($param) {
    case 'login':
        loginProc();
        break;
}

function loginProc()
{
    pdo_mysql_nonquery($somequery,$somearrayparameters);
}    
?>
```

> dbprovider.php

```
<?php
include "config.php";
function pdo_mysql_nonquery($query,$params)
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset={$charset}",$dbusername,$dbpassword) or die("Couldn't connect to the database.");
    $query = $conn->prepare($query);
    return ($params == null ? $query->execute() : $query->execute($params));
}
?>
```

> config.php

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$dbusername = 'root';
$dbpassword = '';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$charset = 'utf-8';
?>
```

my problem is, i must be doing something wrong cause when i call `pdo_mysql_nonquery()` in main.php, i get this error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: host
Notice: Undefined variable: dbname
Notice: Undefined variable: charset
Notice: Undefined variable: dbusername
Notice: Undefined variable: dbpassword
```

when i directly call dbprovider.php and echo the connection string, it prints out fine.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included the file, but values are not passed on to your function.

```
<?php

    function pdo_mysql_nonquery($query,$params)
    {
        include "config.php";// move here
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset={$charset}",$dbusername,$dbpassword) or die("Couldn't connect to the database.");
        $query = $conn->prepare($query);
        return ($params == null ? $query->execute() : $query->execute($params));
    }
```

?>

Or make those variables as `GLOBAL VARIABLES` so that they can be accessed anywhere in your file.

Comment: Oh jeez. I thought these includes work like `using` in C#. Thank you so much. I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing variables out of their scope:

```
<?php
function pdo_mysql_nonquery($query,$params)
{
    include "config.php";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset={$charset}",$dbusername,$dbpassword) or die("Couldn't connect to the database.");
    $query = $conn->prepare($query);
    return ($params == null ? $query->execute() : $query->execute($params));
}
?>
```

or

```
<?php
include "config.php";
function pdo_mysql_nonquery($query,$params)
{
    global $host;
    global $dbname;
    // and so on
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset={$charset}",$dbusername,$dbpassword) or die("Couldn't connect to the database.");
    $query = $conn->prepare($query);
    return ($params == null ? $query->execute() : $query->execute($params));
}
?>
```

But i'd recommend against global variables.

And as an explanation, both `include` and `require` simply take the content of the files and evaluate it in your current scope.

In your particular case, the db credential variables were created above the function. Thus not being accessible inside the function.